# Why ONNX model results differ when inferred from Python and from C++?

Tags: onnxruntime

Designed ONNX Model for Iris dataset, where ONNX model input is array of float numbers and output is label.

While inferring this ONNX model in C++ using 'Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime\1.13.1\runtimes', for same set of input, output label is different WRT prediction done using Python Inference.

```
C++ Code Snippet for ONNX Infererence

// Set up options for session
Ort::SessionOptions sessionOptions;
sessionOptions.SetIntraOpNumThreads(1);

// Sets graph optimization level (Here, enable all possible optimizations)
sessionOptions.SetGraphOptimizationLevel(GraphOptimizationLevel::ORT_ENABLE_EXTENDED);

std::string instanceName{ "Test Inference" };
mEnv = std::make_shared<Ort::Env>(OrtLoggingLevel::ORT_LOGGING_LEVEL_WARNING, instanceName.c_str());

// use it....
mSession = std::make_shared<Ort::Session>(*mEnv, pwcsName, sessionOptions);

// Create input tensors of ORT::Value, which is a tensor format used by ONNX Runtime
Ort::MemoryInfo memoryInfo = Ort::MemoryInfo::CreateCpu(OrtAllocatorType::OrtDeviceAllocator,                                     OrtMemType::OrtMemTypeCPU);

auto input_tensor = Ort::Value::CreateTensor<float>(memoryInfo, inputTensorValues.data(),
            inputTensorSize, mInputDims.data(), mInputDims.size());
        
 auto output_tensors = mSession->Run(Ort::RunOptions{ nullptr }, inputNames.data(), &input_tensor, 1, outputNames.data(), 1);

// Get the inference result
float* outArr = output_tensors.front().GetTensorMutableData<float>()
assert(abs(outArr[0] - 0.000045) < 1e-6);

// score the model, and print scores for label classes
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            std::cout << "Score for class [" << i << "] =  " << outArr[i] << '\n';

}
std::cout << std::flush;

int64_t cls_idx = std::max_element(outArr, outArr + count) - outArr;
m_label = labels[cls_idx];
```

std::vectorstd::string labels = { "setosa", "versicolor", "virginica" };
[Prediction Label differs only when inferred from C++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1dKh.png)

Please help me understand why results from these 2 Inferences are not matching.

Expected : Output labels from Python and C++ inferences shall be same